# How to change the forward speed when near the objetctive netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

i have bird that can fly really long distances, so it has a foward of 5. However its not reaching its destination as flying in intervals of 5 makes it jump the mark. To solve it i tried this.

`ask Buteo-platypterus[ face min-one-of patches with [pcolor = green ] [distance myself] ifelse distance patches with [pcolor = green] < 5 [fd 1][ fd 5 set energia energia - 5] ]`

Distance expects an agent or patch but it's getting an agentset. How do i make the bird go slower when its near the destination?

Comment: Considering that the bird can fly a distance of 5 per tick, do you want it to go slower or do you want it to be able to directly reach the target if the target is closer than 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse distance patches with [pcolor = green][...]`
This line of code is your problem. You are asking the distance to all green patches, an agentsent, instead of to the closest green patch.

```
ifelse distance min-one-of patches with [pcolor = green] [distance myself] [...]
```

This should solve the problem. You could also use a local variable to not have to rewrite the same code over and over again (which can lead to mistakes)

```
ask Buteo-platypterus [ 
   let destination min-one-of patches with [pcolor = green ] [distance myself] 
   face destination 
   ifelse distance destination < 5 [fd 1][ fd 5 set energia energia - 5] 
]
```

Comment: Thanks! does it work if i say iifelse destination < 5 [fd 1][ fd 5 set energia energia - 5]

Comment: Oh right, I completely left out the <5 part in the rewrite. Sorry for that